# Mostrar datas específicas que estão no Banco de dados no Bootstrap datapicker

Tags: php, javascript, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, mysqli

Preciso que o datapicker carregue datas específicas dinamicamente, que estão salvas no banco de dados, consegui fazer com que ele carregue manualmente, porém são diversas datas e podem variar conforme o usuário salvar no banco de dados.

Estou utilizando o seguinte código, que exibe as datas manualmente selecionas com uma cor específica:

```
<script>
var active_dates = ["2-9-2019","22-9-2019"];

$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
     var d = date;
     var curr_date = d.getDate();
     var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1;
     var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
     var formattedDate = curr_date + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_year

       if ($.inArray(formattedDate, active_dates) != -1){
           return {
              classes: 'activeClass'
           };
       }
      return;
  }
});
$(".datepicker").attr("autocomplete", "off");
</script>
```

CSS:

```
.activeClass{
color: #ecf0f1;
background: #2980b9; 
}
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após algumas pesquisas e estudos vi que é possível passar dados de uma variável php para javascript. Exemplificando:

```
<?php
 $color = "Red";
?>
```

No javascript:

```
var color = "<?php echo $color; ?>";
```

Estou tentando do seguinte modo, porém sem sucesso!:

```
<?php 
  $diasValidos = $this->db->get_where('school_days')->result_array();
?>
```

No Datapicker:

```
<script>
var active_dates = <?php $diasValidos ?>;

$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
     var d = date;
     var curr_date = d.getDate();
     var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1;
     var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
     var formattedDate = curr_date + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_year

       if ($.inArray(formattedDate, active_dates) != -1){
           return {
              classes: 'activeClass'
           };
       }
      return;
  }
});
$(".datepicker").attr("autocomplete", "off");
</script>
```

Print da tabela no banco de dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já tentou: `var active_dates = [<?php echo implode("','",$diasValidos) ?>];`

Comment: Pedro, dê um var_dump($this->db->get_where('school_days')->result_array()); e posta o resultado, por favor. Precisamos observar o que tem neste seu retorno

Comment: array(4) { ["id"]=> string(1) "5" ["day"]=> string(2) "21" ["month"]=> string(1) "1" ["year"]=> string(4) "2019" }, está assim! Vou tirar um print do bd e postar na pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Existem dois possíveis problemas, provavelmente o retorno de

```
$diasValidos = $this->db->get_where('school_days')->result_array()
```

não está vindo com um array de datas, e se você estiver buscando as datas no banco, e a coluna estiver como datetime, o retorno da data será Y-m-d, então a forma como está formantando a data para comparar está errada.

Como pedido, é necessário saber o retorno para $diasValidos, para podermos ajudar.

**EDITADO:**

Considerando o retorno `array(4) { ["id"]=> string(1) "5" ["day"]=> string(2) "21" ["month"]=> string(1) "1" ["year"]=> string(4) "2019" },`

Apenas refatore o seu array para juntar o dia, mês e ano, uma forma seria:

```
$diasValidos = array_map(function($diaValido) {
    return $diaValido['day'] + "-" + $diaValido['month'] + "-" + $diaValido['year'];
}, $diasValidos);
```

Comment: Dei um  var_dump e está retornando null!